# How to access response message returned from server on frontend using the fetch api in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay, this is a pretty simple question.

I am returning a 400 status error along side a message "Index should have 6 digits" message back in my response.

I am using React for my front-end. When I log the body of the response using the fetch api [`console.log(response.json())`], I can see that I receive it properly. 
[image: response.json()]

But for some reason I cannot access it any any way. 
Also, I don't know why the status `statusText` field in the response is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

What is the defacto standard for exception handling from server side?

Thank you.

Edit - code:

```
errorHandler = (response) => {
    if (!response.ok){
        console.log(response.json());
        throw Error(response.statusMessage);
    }
    else {
        return response;
    }
};

addStudent = (student) => {
    createStudent(student)
        .then(this.errorHandler)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('new student status: ', response.status);
            this.loadData();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

Comment: So what does your code actually look like that does not work?

Comment: Updated the code, please check

Comment: Change response.statusMessage to response.message

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that your're getting a `Promise` object back in your console, this means that your request simply hasn't fulfilled yet.

Chain onto the promise with `.then(response => { // handle the response here })`

The code should look similar to this:

```
fetch('/endpoint').then(response => {
    console.log(response)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated the code, mine is very similar to what you wrote. I need to read the response message returned from the server

Answer (score 0):

What I do is what Mike wrote above.

```
fetch("endpoint")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data.message));
```